# Trying to add a Refresh Method to a WebView and having issues

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to add a simple swipe refresh to a webview layout. I have searched all over and tried different methods from things that I have found on GitHub and Android Developers pages but nothing seems to work. When I load the web page with the code without the OnRefresh method in the code it loads just fine. But as soon as I enable the method the page just closes the application. Any advice would be great as I'm new to android (1 yr exp) and trying to learn. Thanks

Here is a sample of the code I'm working with. Hope I don't post to much info every time I ask a question here I get told I'm posting too much!!

```
private AboutViewModel AboutViewModel;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root;
    AboutViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AboutViewModel.class);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

        WebView webView = root.findViewById(R.id.web_view_about);
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

This is the layout xml

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you add `swipe.setRefreshing(false);` after `webView.reload();` ?

Comment: Still closes.

Logcat: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: I think its referring to this?

swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

Comment: `swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.swipe); swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()` - Naah! It's fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace container with **root** like below:

```
swipe = root.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
                swipe.setRefreshing(false); // Call this at the end of loading
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I can't click the "This answer was useful because I had to make a new account to login today but THANKS A MILLION!!!  I spent at least 26 hours looking at different codes trying to figure out why it would close!  Downloaded tons of samples on Github and nothing helped!  I can see now why Google Developers said during the Google I/O that Stack Over Flow is outdated and questions are too old for answers that work now days!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: Now if I could add the `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()` to the whole thing I'd be done :) but it works the way it is.  When I add that it closes once more.  Don't know if I should just make it an activity or if that matters.